# git: How two laptops can git push/pull to each other over internet

Tags: windows, git

say we are 2 colleagues in which one is having permission to pull from github and another don't have. But the other user have to work on the project with pulling from the colleagues laptop.

Can we do that?

Comment: Do you have a way to share files now? Is your source on a local hard drive, a network drive?

Comment: no not yet. Yes the source is on the local drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can certainly work, but will require some manual coordination to communicate one laptop's current IP address to the other user, or alternatively configuring the laptop with a dynamic dns provider to associate a static name to whatever the current IP address is. Then there's considerations about firewalls, routers (including maybe some port forwarding and NAT issues), etc., depending on how exactly the two systems connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you have permissions to see each others Windows file shares you can configure each as a remote using UNC paths. If your partner 'fred' has shared 'Code' on FREDSPC you can configure the remote as `git remote add fred //FREDSPC/Code/projectfolder` then `git fetch fred` will work as normal, pulling in the commits from their repository over the Windows network filesystem.